# PostgreSQL: SELECT DISTINCT vs SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, select, distinct

Let many users belong to many groups.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE group_members (
    group_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES groups ON DELETE CASCADE,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES users ON DELETE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (group_id, user_id)
);
```

Get the set of all users that belong to groups.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, username
FROM groups AS g
JOIN group_members AS m
ON m.group_id = g.id
JOIN users AS u
ON u.id = m.user_id
```

See [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cd78a0/5).

Would it be faster to use `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)` (in the `SELECT` query above) instead of `SELECT DISTINCT`?

Both queries return the same result set. I'd rather use `SELECT DISTINCT` because it's cleaner.

But, imagine the `users` table had several more columns. Would `SELECT DISTINCT` be smart enough to just check the `id` column (instead of all columns) for duplicates?

Comment: Test it and try it out on your data.  Because they return the same result set with and without the distinct, this is not something that one would normally think about.  The two versions should be doing the same amount of work.

Comment: Why would you bother using `SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)` if id is a unique key (assuming no joins in the query)? It's like appending "+ 5000 - 5000" to every arithmetic expression in your code. It's a no-op and *might* be factored out by a compiler, but why would you do that?

Comment: K. Yeah. I wouldn't, unless it's a huge difference in performance. I figure PostgreSQL is smart enough to only check the `id` column for `SELECT DISTINCT`, but I don't know and am curious because I want to do the right thing.

Comment: @mattdipasquale: You seem to be missing Bill's and Gordon's point. *Both* queries are nonsense. With a PK in `id` all rows are distinct either way. Drop `DISTINCT` from the query altogether.

Comment: Guys, thank you for your comments. Good point! I didn't think of that. I'm sorry for the confusion. I've clarified my question.

Comment: If you really want to know which one is faster, try it with real-life data and check the execution plans generated by `explain analyze`.

Comment: I would expect the `distinct on()`  to be (slightly) faster though, as it only requires comparison/sorting on the `id` column. Whereas `distinct id, username` will do that on both columns (even if not necessary). The optimizer is not smart enough to see that the id is the only thing needed. You could also try `group by id` instead - that is valid because the id is the PK

Comment: OK. Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* the distinct if you select *only* from the users table
(the users are already distinct, I expect)

```
SELECT u.id, u.username
FROM users AS u
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
    FROM  group_members AS m
    WHERE u.id = m.user_id
    );
```

And you don't need to join the groups table, since the FK in the group_members table *guarantees* that it exists.

Comment: Documentation suggest that a subquery used for EXISTS return `SELECT 1` since we do not need to retrieve any column from that table.

Comment: @KamilG. Please show the link to the Postgres documentation where it states that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name implicitly in [Subquery expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html) example. I just tend to follow docs in that case, but execution plans should be the same.

Comment: Nothing there says that `select 1` is faster then `select *` - it actually says: "*the output list of the subquery is normally unimportant*" This is an urban myth that has never been true. It is completely irrelevant to the performance where you use `select *` or `select 1`  unless e.g. the subselect uses `union` or `intersect` as the manual also points out.

Comment: @KamilG. It is a matter of style or preference (I've even seen `SELECT NULL... )`; the whole result of the subquery is thrown away anyway and the whole `exists(... subquery ...)` decays into a boolean term.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I believe that in my comment I've already stated that I know the performance does not vary and I wrote that documentation suggests that MERELY in its example. wildplasser, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @wildplasser the query in your answer gives me a syntax error at `JOIN` on line 2.

Comment: Ok fixed. Thanks! (I am worthless without an editor ...)